# Python threads do something at the EXACT same time

Tags: python, multithreading, request

Is it possible to have 2, 3 or more threads in Python to be able to execute something simultaneously - at the exact same moment? Is it possible if one of the threads is late, for the other to be waiting for it, so the last request can be executed at the same time?

Example: There are two threads that are calculating specific parameters, after they have done that they need to click one button at the same time (to send post request to the server).

Comment: Threads in Python are actually not executed concurrently: the interpreter works single-threaded, so only one thread is active at the same time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how about Jython etc?

Comment: Thanks. It's good first to check and then to ask ... sorry ;)

Comment: Threads could be beneficial if you're doing some IO intensive work. Otherwise subprocesses could help with cost of serializing/deserializing data for each worker. What author asks sound more like locking and synchronizing between threads. @SimeonPopov, what would you like to achieve? Why do you need to click a button? Could you make a request directly from python?

Comment: Just as well that threads are single threaded. In a relativistic universe, whether two events appear to occur simultaneously will vary from observer to observer. What is simultaneous to us on Earth may appear sequential to someone on a spaceship approaching light speed ;-)

Comment: @grundic I will make a request from python. This request simulate clicking on button.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem First of all: that's not true. Threads in Python **are** active concurrently for example when waiting for i/o.

Comment: @SimeonPopov Secondly "at the same time" doesn't make any sense since not many things in the universe happen at the same point in time. You need some precision. At the same time up to what? Millisecond? Microsecond? The answer heavily depends on that. Some precision is achievable in Python, some is not. With very high precision this is not doable in any known language.

Comment: @freakish: but when you are waiting, you are not actively waiting. Python will place the thread in a queue until the I/O is done and then awake the thread again. I/O is not done by Python: it does calls to the OS. What I mean is that in the Python environment, there is only one thread that does Python evaluations. By using threads you can get 100% of one core. But not two or more cores. So calculations are done on one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

"Exact the same time" is really difficult, at almost the same time is possible but you need to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of threads. Here one example.

```
from time import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f(*args):
    while time() < start + 5: #syncronize the execution of each process
        pass
    print(time())

start = time()

with Pool(10) as p:
    p.map(f, range(10))
```

It prints

```
1495552973.6672032
1495552973.6672032
1495552973.669514
1495552973.667697
1495552973.6672032
1495552973.668086
1495552973.6693969
1495552973.6672032
1495552973.6677089
1495552973.669164
```

Note that some of the processes are really simultaneous (in the 10e-7 second precision). It's impossible to guarantee that all the processes will be executed at the very same moment.
However, if you limitate the number of processes to the number of core you actually have, then most of the time they will run exactly at the same moment.

Comment: I know how multiprocessing works. But I need time less then 10e-7 seconds. Anyway. In python is impossible ;)